# How to align text in a padded-out input-field/ box?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm making an application for the company I'm interning with. I've completed a part of the front end and there was one small problem I needed help with. The code is at

https://github.com/ZeusEm/AirIndia-WebAlert

Or else you may shoot up the landing page straight up by clicking

http://zeusem.github.io/AirIndia-WebAlert/

```css
input {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em 19%;
  max-width: 30vmin;
}
```

```html
<input class="data glowing-border" type="text" name="username" required="" autofocus="" placeholder="Username">
<input class="data glowing-border" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password">
```

As you might see, the input fields have their placeholder brought left because of the extra (necessary) padding I gave. Can anybody here suggest me something as to how align the placeholder (and hence the text) with the left border of the input field?

Comment: You mean to say that the padding must be there but the space before shouldn't be?

Comment: Exactly. The padding was added because I want to make this as mobile friendly as possible (and bigger box sizes help in that). But I want the text to be left or center aligned because the current setup looks just odd.

Comment: Going by your statement - *left or center aligned* - can you just not add the `text-align: center` to the `input`. That should solve it. If you want left-align you can try using `text-indent: -[padding-left]` but what I've seen in the past is that it hides part of the text.

Comment: Okay. I felt the box sizes have been altered and since the cursor is placed so far right making it text-align to center would shift it even more right. But it all works. Text-align center works. Thank you. Really stupid of me.

Comment: No problems :) I would add it as an answer. If you don't mind edit in this part (center align is ok) into the question so that the answer doesn't look irrelevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [comment that either left or center align would be fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512440/how-to-align-text-in-a-padded-out-input-field-box#comment62518410_37512440), I would suggest going with center align option by using `text-align` center on the `input` element. This option would be lot more easier to achieve than left align with padding.

```css
input {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em 19%;
  max-width: 30vmin;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input class="data glowing-border" type="text" name="username" required="" autofocus="" placeholder="Username">
<input class="data glowing-border" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password">
```